# Google Visualization API load spreadsheet data as CSV-like JSON

Tags: json, csv, google-visualization

I try to load data from a Google spreadsheet in JSON format. As a response I receive JSON like...

```
{
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'column_A', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'B', label: 'column_B', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'C', label: 'column_C', type: 'string'}
  ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: '1'},
             {v: '2'},
             {v: '3'}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: 'a'},
             {v: 'b'},
             {v: 'c'}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: '1'},
             {v: '2'},
             {v: '3'}
        ]}
  ]
}
```

...but what I need is a JSON formated like CSV converted to JSON

```
[{'column_A': 1,
  'column_B': 2,
  'column_C': 3
 },
 {'column_A': 'a',
  'column_B': 'b',
  'column_C': 'c'
 },
 {'column_A': 1,
  'column_B': 2,
  'column_C': 3
 }]
```

Any idea how to do that? Your help is much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the `map` method to transform the `rows` array
use the `cols` array to name each row

see following working snippet...

```js
var jsonGoogle = {
  cols: [
    {id: 'A', label: 'column_A', type: 'string'},
    {id: 'B', label: 'column_B', type: 'string'},
    {id: 'C', label: 'column_C', type: 'string'}
  ],
  rows: [
    {c:[
      {v: '1'},
      {v: '2'},
      {v: '3'}
    ]},
    {c:[
      {v: 'a'},
      {v: 'b'},
      {v: 'c'}
    ]},
    {c:[
      {v: '1'},
      {v: '2'},
      {v: '3'}
    ]}
  ]
};

var jsonCSV = jsonGoogle.rows.map(function (row) {
  var rowCSV = {};
  jsonGoogle.cols.forEach(function (col, index) {
    rowCSV[col.label] = row.c[index].v;
  });
  return rowCSV;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonCSV));
```

Comment: Hey @WhiteHat works lika a charm, many thanks! One issue I still have: in the response I cannot rule out `null` in *cols*. I tried to tackle this with checking for `typeof(row.c[index]) == null` and creating empty `{v: ''}` instead. But unfortunatelly, the `forEach` already seems to struggle with `null`. Do you have an idea how to overcome this issue? Thanks again! `try { response.cols.forEach(function (col, index) { if (typeof(row.c[index]) == null) { throw {...} } rowCSV[col.label] = row.c[index].v; }); } catch(error) {...}`

Comment: I'm requesting data from Google using G.'s query language `var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/...'); query.setQuery('...');` Unfortunatelly, query language doesn't support any ÌFNULL` or `IF` conditions I could use to replace `null` already while fetching data.

Comment: there are `null` values in the `cols` array? if so --> `if (col === null)`